# Building a CV using online tools: is it good or bad from HR perspective?

Tags: resume, human-resources

I have built a new version of my CV using online tools, and I want to send it to a HR dept in some company, but I asked myself is this good or bad from HR perspective?
What the employer may think about it?

I can remove the header and what may refer to the tool used in building the CV

Comment: Why *would* it be either good or bad that you have used "online tools"? Is there something about the formatting you are worried about? It touting the tool used to make it (but you specifically say you can remove that)? Or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *content* of your CV is what matters, not how you got there.

If the output of your online tool is a terrific resume, you'll be in good shape, if not, you'll have problems. Terrific resumes don't look like they are built from a template, and don't have tool-name headers, watermarks, etc. Terrific resumes reflect *you*, and put forward *your* best attributes, not generic attributes.

While HR doesn't care what tools you used, the name and any references to the tool should be removed. The same would be true if someone helped you create your resume - you wouldn't put your friend's name in your resume's header.

I've read a lot of resumes over the years. I never cared (and usually never knew) if the resume was crafted using Notepad, Word, or Bob's Super Crafty Amazing Online Resume Wizard and List Builder. If the resume did a good job of selling the candidate, it was good enough in my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that many of the tools that HR uses in the hiring process require the resume to be in text file format. It is a good idea to look at any resume/CV you make after it has been pasted into a text editor.

Most resumes are created with the help of either a tool or a expert. Many new graduates use an office at their university to help make their first resume. Employees losing coverage are given resume help by a company office or an outside company. The military frequently provides resume assistance to soldiers leaving the military.

Even long time employees will find that their current company requires a yearly resume update so they can use their skill sets when bidding on contracts. These proposals frequently have specific and unique formatting and length requirements. Some times these modifications are done by the employee, and sometimes they are done by the team preparing the bid.

Therefore almost every resume has been massaged by a tool or an "expert".

If you remove the headers and any other links to the software nobody will be the wiser, and nobody will care.